# Having trouble with WHERE DATEDIFF in my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I think I'm going about this wrong.  I want to pull the rows in my database that are less than a day old, in PHP.  I'm using Laravel, but that's not relevant.  Here is what I have:

```
if ($day == 'today') {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
} elseif ($day == 'yesterday') {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('yesterday'));
} else {
    ...
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM all_forms_main_contact WHERE DATEDIFF(timestamp, '" . $date . "') <= 1";
$mc = DB::select($sql);
return json_encode($mc);
```

However, that isn't return the right results.  It's return results older than a day.

Comment: `timestamp` is a DATETIME field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query selects rows that are newer than -24 hours.
For example if it is 04:00 AM then return all rows >= yesterday 04:00 AM:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Likewise for newer than -48 hours.
For example if it is 04:00 AM then return all rows >= day before yesterday 04:00 AM:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

This query selects today's rows.
For example if it is 04:00 AM then return all rows >= today 00:00 AM:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `datetime` >= CURDATE()
```

Likewise, this query selects yesterday's rows only.
For example if it is 04:00 AM then return all rows between yesterday 00:00 AM through (but not including) today 00:00 AM:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `datetime` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `datetime` < CURDATE()
```

<sub>I use the above syntax for dates queries, which I believe is far more readable than date add/sub functions.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on how you define "less than a day old".

The MySQL `DATEDIFF` function only considers the date portion of the datetime values, and returns an integer number of days difference. Both of the queries below will return a value of 1, representing "1 day", where one is a difference of 8 hours, the other is a difference of 46 hours:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2013-01-15 07:00','2013-01-14 23:00') AS 8_hrs
SELECT DATEDIFF('2013-01-15 23:00','2013-01-14 01:00') AS 46_hrs
```

So, it's entirely possible and expected that rows "older" than 24 hours might be returned by your query.

(The `hh:mi:ss` time portion of the literal being supplied as an argument to the DATEDIFF function is   being ignored, and the time portion of the timestamp values are being ignored. You would get the same result by supplying just the `YYYY-MM-DD` value.)

---

Also note that the predicate on the DATEDIFF function is not sargable, that is, MySQL cannot do a range scan on an index to satisfy that predicate.

For best performance, we generally prefer equivalent predicates that are on the bare column, e.g.

```
WHERE `timestamp` >= expr
```

which enables the optimizer to at least consider using a range scan on an index on the `timestamp` column.

If you are looking for row less than 1 day old (meaning less than 24 hours old, or less than 86400 seconds old), with a resolution up to a second, you could use a predicate like one of these:

```
WHERE `timestamp` >= '2013-01-15 16:10' + INTERVAL -1 DAY
WHERE `timestamp` >= '2013-01-15 16:10' + INTERVAL -24 HOUR
WHERE `timestamp` >= '2013-01-15 16:10' + INTERVAL -86400 SECOND
```

The DATE_ADD function is equivalent:

```
WHERE `timestamp` >= DATE_ADD('2013-01-15 16:10',INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Also note that it's not necessary to pass in the current date value as a literal in the SQL text; MySQL provides builtin functions that return the current date and time from the MySQL server, such as `NOW()`, `CURRENT_DATE()` and `SYSDATE()`.

For rows that are less than 24 hours old or 48 hours old, respectively:

```
WHERE `timestamp` >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)
WHERE `timestamp` >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
SELECT ... WHERE timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally code it simply like this:

```
...
where timestamp > subdate(now(), 1)
```

Note the convenient version of [`subdate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) that allows days to be specified as a simple integer (ie the default interval type is `DAY`). Also, subdate returns a datetime if the first parameter is a daretine.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas DATEDIFF ignores the time component (see [DATEDIFF - MariaDB Knowledge](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datediff/) ), TIMESTAMPDIFF doesn't. So this would work:

```
SELECT ... WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `timestamp`) = '0'
```

For example if NOW() =  '2020-01-02 00:00:01' and `timestamp` is '2020-01-01 01:00:00' the above code would accurately return 0 days, but DATEDIFF would incorrectly return 1 day (as it ignores the time component.